# Can't import QSound from PyQt5.QtGui

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to use QSound for my application, but whenever I try to import it I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QSound'
```

Using python console with no success, as:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QSound
```

I tried to import it from `PyQt5.QtCore` and `PyQt5` Same error.

Comment: from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @S. Nick , the correct import was

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
```